# Drop Duplicates based on condition of two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have this table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | A | C |
| Hello | B | C |
| Hello | C | C |

And I would like to drop duplicates based on column A, but keep only the third row, where the columns B and C have the same string:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | C | C |

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df[~df['A'].duplicated(keep=False)|(df['C']==df['B'])]
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I only want to do it for duplicated rows on column A. So for example, if any row with a unique value in A don't have the same values in B and C, it would be removed with your code, and I'd like to keep it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
df = df[df.C.eq(df.B) | ~df.A.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I only want to do it for duplicated rows on column A. So for example, if any row with a unique value in A don't have the same values in B and C, it would be removed with your code, and I'd like to keep it. Thanks!

Comment: @BENY was thinking `|` on `~` of the duplicated